# Como pegar textos e imagens de arquivo pdf

Tags: python, pdf

Preciso pegar texto e imagens de um arquivo pdf. Tentei utilizar a PyPDF2, mas com ela estou conseguindo pegar apenas o texto. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: O que você já tentou?